# android default listview pressed state color code

Tags: android, xml

I need to know the android's default listview pressed state color code in 4.3
or is there any other way to set it while rowview is pressed while i am using custom background for rowview..
like,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/????"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_light_gray"/>
</selector>
```

Please help..

Answer (score -1):

You can using "listSelector" in ListView to set selected color.

Example:

> < ListView
>      
> android:listSelector="#ffffffff"
>      />

Comment: This isn't what Irfan require.